# Como fazer um log de um post em uma web api

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

Quero saber o que a *Web Api* está a receber no Post que eu estou a enviar.

> Este é o código que estou a usar.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://d6dc30b8-0ee0-4-231-b9ee.azurewebsites.net/");
                    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/vnd.lyoness.servicesv1 + json";
                    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Date" + tempo); 

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();

                }
                MessageBox.Show(json);

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var teste = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(teste);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo usar [Fluent HTTP](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/) para isso. Além de ser mais elegante para realizar requests HTTP, vem vários outros recursos como esse que precisa:

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(c => {
    c.BeforeCallAsync = DoSomethingBeforeCallAsync;
    c.AfterCallAsync = DoSomethingAfterCallAsync;
    c.OnErrorAsync = HandleErrorAsync;
});
```

Para fazer um `POST`:

```
await "http://api.foo.com".PostJsonAsync(new { a = 1, b = 2 });
```

Fonte: http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/configuration/

Comment: como posso usar o Fluent HTTP com o meu código ?

Comment: Basta seguir a documentação, é bem simples de entender. Veja aqui http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/

Comment: Como eu posso baixar essa assembly ?